# Sitecore query: Get first ancestor that matches condition

Tags: sitecore

I have the following sitecore query:

```
./ancestor::*[@@templatename='Template 1' or @@templatename='Template 2']//*[@@templatename='Target']/*
```

which works, but if the the context item have both Template 1 and 2 as an ancestor, i get double results. So i basically want to stop at the first ancestor who matches the template. I've tried getting the first match like this:

```
./ancestor::*[@@templatename='Template 1' or @@templatename='Template 2'][1]//*[@@templatename='Target']/*
```

But that results in an error. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```lua
./ancestor::*[@@templatename='Template 1' or @@templatename='Template 2']/.[1]/*[@@templatename='Target']/*
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that what you are trying to do is possible with a query. The position match [1] that you trying is based on the position (index) of a child item and not the position in your results.

I see 2 options for you:

- use your first query, get double results and use a distinct function on it in code
- use something else (search api?) to get your results..

That is of course if you are querying in code - if you are trying to set a source for a field it's going to be more difficult.